# Running Blender 2.8 and 2.7 on same PC

Tags: installation

I'm trying to run Blender 2.8 and 2.7 on same PC. When using the installer 2.8 will remove 2.7 and 2.7 won't install with 2.8 already on the PC. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

If you want multiple blender versions (I have three) to play nicely together you have to download them as zips and then extract them instead of just running the installer.

Alternately you can put your older blender installations into zip files, run the installer, and then unzip the old versions again back to where they were. I have used this method myself in the past but it's so much easier to just get the zip for the latest version to start with.

I got this answer in part from [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/can-i-have-2-versions-of-blender-installed/1112745).

Answer (score 0):

You need to Download zip file instead of (.msc file) and then unzip the file > Find The Blender.exe file > Run This File > Here You Go Using This Method You can Run Blender 2.79 On Your PC, While Blender 2.80 is Installed in Your Computer